# How to display multiple images in tkinter using loop?

Tags: python, image, loops, tkinter

I want to display multiple images on my tkinter window using for loop.
The window is only displaying the last image. How can I solve tht?
I m kind of new to tkinter and python.
The following is my code:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * from Contacts ORDER BY NAME")

show_result = mycursor.fetchall()

name_list = []
contact_list = []
email_list = []
dob_list = []
category_list = []
profile_location = []

for row in show_result:
    name_list.append(row[0])
    contact_list.append(row[1])
    email_list.append(row[2])
    dob_list.append(row[3])
    category_list.append(row[4])
    profile_location.append(row[5])

name_length = len(name_list)

a = 200

b = 30
c = 50

imgx = 10
imgy = 20


for i in range(0, name_length):
    name = name_list[i]
    contact = contact_list[i]
    email = email_list[i]
    dob = dob_list[i]
    category = category_list[i]
    profile = profile_location[i]

    img_open = Image.open(profile)
    img_tst = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_open)

    label_name = Label(seewindow, image=img_tst)
    label_name.place(x=imgx, y=imgy)

    a += 200
    imgx += 250
```

Comment: Try adding ```label_name.image=img_tst```

Comment: @Sujay The isn't going to help because `label_name` is written over so technically it goes out of scope

Comment: Put all of the `img_tst`s in a list.

Comment: @TheLizzard It works somehow my problem is solved thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add after `label_name.place`. the local variable gets garbage collected. Save a reference of the photo using

```
label_name.image=img_tst
```

Comment: If `name_length` is more than 1, the variable `label_name` will be overwritten. That causes the old `label_name` to be garbage collected. Therefore, this isn't a solution that will work in most cases.